# I'm getting device disconnected in logcat

Tags: android-logcat

I'm getting device disconnected in logcat. I'm trying to dial * # * #2846579# *# * for menu but as soon as I dial it, it disappears and nothing happens. Kindly help.

Comment: device did not disconnect for me.I use android Studio.